# Are there any major differences in metric topologies and "non-symmetric" metric topologies

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a set and let $d:X\times X\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ satisfy all the axioms of a metric besides symmetry (i.e.: $d$ is a quasi-metric).  Define a topology $\tau_{d:+}$ on $X$ induced by $d$ as generated by the sub-basic open sets $\{U_{\epsilon,x}\}_{x \in X,\epsilon>0}$ where:
$$
U_{\epsilon,x}:=
\left\{
y \in X:\, d(x,y)<\epsilon
\right\}.
$$

*Are there any major differences between this type of "asymmetric metric" topology and those topologies generated by regular metrics?*

**Details of what I mean:**

- The positive definite axiom, for me, looks like this: $d(x,y)=0 \Leftarrow x=y$; but the converse may fail.  Here, I can at-least imagine that the Hausdorff property may be damaged, but I can't make things concrete...
- Are such topologies $T_6$ (i.e.: perfectly normal Hausdorff spaces) or do they satisfy some more basic separation axioms?

*Note:*  Is there a good reference that discusses such constructions in some depth?

Comment: In view of the deleted answer, should you clarify what the positive definite axiom looks like for you?  Is it $d(x,y)=0$ implies $x=y$, or $d(x,y)=d(y,x)=0$ implies $x=y$?

Comment: @NateEldredge (Details added) I'm only looking for a assymmetric version of the positive definite axiom.

Comment: It would be still better if you would write down exactly the axioms you mean. For example, I am not sure whether $d(x,y)=0$ if $x\leqslant y$ and $d(x,y)=1$ otherwise is fine for you.

Comment: If you allow $d(x,y) = 0 \implies x=y$ to fail, then you would seem to allow the trivial "distance" given by $d(x,y)=0$ for all $x,y$.  This of course induces the indiscrete topology which satisfies no separation axioms at all.  If that is not what you mean, then I think you'd better write out your complete set of axioms, in full.  In particular, it seems that you have in mind something rather different than [what most people mean by quasi-metric](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Quasi-metric)